# Не работает vpn клиент wireguard windows 11

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, vpn, wireguard

У меня есть сервер vpn wireguard который прекрасно работает. Я подключаюсь к нему из ubuntu 20.04 и со своего телефона на android. И там и там нет никаких проблем. Но есть проблема на windows 11. Там при подключении к впн просто пропадает интернет. Я пробовал скармливать те же самые конфиги что и ubuntu клиенту и андроид клиенту. Но оно не работает. Вообще никак. Так же я пробовал создавать нового юзера на сервере и скармливать его конфиг windows клиенту. Тоже не работает. Делаю ctrl+c ctrl+v Этого конфига на линукс и всё запускается с первой попытки. Из этого я сделал два вывода:

1. Никаких проблем с сервером нет (иначе почему линукс и андроид клиенту отлично работают?)
2. Никаких проблем с конфигом клиента так же нет. Потому что когда я скармливаю тот же самый конфиг линукс и андроид клиента то всё прекрасно работает.

Значит проблема исключительно с моим любимым майкрософтом и его виндой, у которого постоянно какие-то танцы с бубном. Конфиг который я вставляю в клиент:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private_key>
Address = 10.0.0.5/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public_key>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <server_ip>:51830
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

Я пробовал отключать брандмауэр винды это никакого профита не принесло. Всё тоже самое. Антивирус только встроенный в винду. Его я тоже пробовал отключать тоже 0 профита. Так же эта проблема не связана с моим роутером. Т.к. линукс установлен на этом же компе и на этом же ssd диске, работает он так же через этот роутер и не имеет никаких проблем. Логи wireguard выглядят так:

```
2022-06-29 23:46:27.267: [TUN] [myvpn] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830)
2022-06-29 23:46:32.428: [TUN] [myvpn] Handshake for peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2022-06-29 23:46:32.428: [TUN] [myvpn] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830)
2022-06-29 23:46:37.437: [TUN] [myvpn] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830)
2022-06-29 23:46:42.515: [TUN] [myvpn] Handshake for peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2022-06-29 23:46:42.515: [TUN] [myvpn] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (<server_ip>:51830)
```

При этом сам клиент пишет что всё ок и соединение активно. То что что-то не так становится понятно только по логам и по тому что нет интернета. В логах он жалуется что не получает ответа от сервера. Но я на 99% уверен что запросы клиента даже не доходят до сервера благодаря винде и где-то теряются во всяких брандмауэрах (хотя я его отключил, непонятно что ещё может быть). Так же заметил интересную особенность. После активации тоннеля адаптер создаётся, но там почему-то написано, что у него нет доступа к интернету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю должно ли так быть в винде. Но это странно, ведь весь трафик после активации через этот адаптер отправляется. А как он отправится если у него нет доступа к инету?

`route print` выводит это (при включенном тоннеле):

```
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 18...........................WireGuard Tunnel
 10...40 b0 76 0d a7 4d ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.69     35
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.5      5
         10.0.0.5  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.5    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.5    261
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.5      5
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.69    291
     192.168.0.69  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.69    291
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.69    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.69    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.69    291
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

Comment: @Sergey я с радостью, как это сделать на винде? Что за таблица маршрутизации?

Comment: @Sergey добавил в свой вопрос вывод этой команды. Не понимаю адрес шлюза должен быть одинаковый у каких маршрутов?

Comment: возможно тебе надо посмотреть в свойствах тоннеля myvpn? покажи что там написано в ip v4

Comment: @Алекс в каких свойствах? Где это смотреть?

Comment: @Sergey туннель мне чтобы в интернет ходить. Это я должен менять на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: @Sergey `traceroute` командная строка не знает, при `tracert` говорит что флаг -n для неё недопустим

Comment: @Sergey если мне надо поменять конфиг, то почему тот же самый конфиг работает на линуксе и в андроиде?

Comment: @Sergey нет там никаких таких опций. Я даже посмотрел много туторилов настройки клиента на винде, у всех конфиг точь в точь такой же как у меня (ну за исключением айпишников и ключей конечно). У них работает у меня нет

Comment: Смущает то, что в таблице маршрутизации нет записи для server_ip, если вы эту запись не удалили для скрытия адреса. Хотя есть техники обходится и без этой таблицы. Предположим, что и wineguard обходится без неё, и с этим аспектом всё в порядке. Тогда проверьте что адрес сервера пингуется (или доступен другим способом), предварительно отключив клиента wineguard. Вместо отключения брендауера, добавьте правила, открывающие трафик на адрес сервера. Ну и проверьте, что в конфиге написан правильный  адрес endpoint:)

Comment: @Sergey Ничего не удалял, адрес сервера пингуется (я запустил на нём nginx, приветственная страница доступна), правила пробовал добавлять, это тоже не помогает, в конифге правильный адрес (я ж копировал его с других клиентов)

Comment: А при запущенном клиенте winguard сервер пингуется? Если нет, то попробовать добавить маршрут `route add server_ip mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1` и проверить пинг/интернет. Так же проверить какой используется dns-сервер. Может проблема в том, что dns-сервер прописан не рабочий.

Comment: @Sergey при запущенном туннеле сервер не пингуется. И было бы оооочень странно если бы он пинговался, а интернета не было. Т.к. пинг происходит по 80 порту, и это равнозначно что пинговать любой другой ip. Зато пингуется 10.0.0.5 (это адрес внутри общей локальной сети с сервером). dns прописан 8.8.8.8, он не может быть нерабочий. Как я понял проблема в том что винда не хочет отправлять запросы через новый интернет адаптер, который создаёт wg. Я пытался заставить её сделать это, задав новому адаптеру приоритет номер 1. Но это не помогает

Comment: @Sergey с помощью wireshark удалось увидеть что пакеты идут всё-таки через правильный интерфейс. Попробовал сделать `route add server_ip mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1`, в ответ получаю `Сбой добавления маршрута: Параметр задан неверно.`

Comment: Вместо `server_ip` надо настоящий адрес впн-сервера в команду подставить. Если так и было подставлено, то даже не знаю в чём дело. И винды нет под рукой проверить. Может вместо 255.255.255.255 тоже адрес сервера указать? А сервер должен пинговаться `ping server_ip` (тоже адрес вместо server_ip подставить:) хоть с туннелем, хоть без туннеля. (Единственная причина что не пингуется - это явное отключение возможности пинга на сервере) Адрес впн-сервера не равнозначен любому другому. Туннель ведь не может сам через себя проключаться:)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отключить и остановить службу win `Маршрутизация и удаленный доступ`. Мне помогло

Comment: и так отключена, проблема осталась

Answer (score 0):

Я также столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой и решение оказалось довольно простым. Создайте новый пир для компа. Если вы уже используете один пир на телефоне, то он не хочет работать на винде.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла смена DNS серверов в конфиге.
Поставил от cloudflare 1.1.1.1 и 1.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос еще актуальный, то необходимо сделать следующее.

Проблема на стороне Windows, на котором установлен Wireguard в качестве сервера.

Вот отличная полная инструкция для настройки:
https://www.henrychang.ca/how-to-setup-wireguard-vpn-server-on-windows/

Отмечу лишь суть данной проблемы:

1. По умолчанию, когда включен общий доступ к Интернету (NAT), **Windows** изменит IP-адрес адаптера на что-то другое (во избежание конфликтов). Однако мы уже знаем, какой IP-адрес мы хотим использовать для Wireguard **Server** (заданный в блоке [interface] в нашей конфигурации wireguard).
   Чтобы изменить IP-адрес по умолчанию, на который переключится Windows, мы можем просто изменить настройку в реестре.
   Откройте редактор реестра и перейдите по следующему пути:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters**

Затем просто измените **ScopeAddress** и **StandaloneDHCPAddress** на нужный нам IP-адрес (Который прописан в [interface] Wireguard-Сервера).

2. После того, как прописан IP в реестре, запустите снова Общий доступ к интернету.
   В PowerShell с правами администратора выполните

**Set-NetConnectionSharing "wg_server" $true**

где **"wg_server"** - Наименование Вашего Wireguard-сервера.

Еще обратите внимание, что после перезагрузки, все это может слетать. В инструкции по ссылке, есть от этого средство.

Comment: сервер wireguard на линуксе

Comment: линукс и винда в одной подсети? (до включения wireguard)

Comment: Нет, зачем им там быть?

Answer (score 0):

Спустя время я переустановил windows. Пробовал на 10 и на 11 винде, оно не работало. Но вдруг несколько раз включив и выключив туннель на клиенте при очередном включении произошло рукопожатие... Теперь оно работает и рукопожатие происходит всегда, даже после перезагрузки windows. Я так и не понял в чём была проблема. Подозреваю что клиент wireguard на windows всё-таки имеет какие-то проблемы и баги

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло в AllowedIps разделить подсеть 0.0.0.0/0 на две: 0.0.0.0/1 и 128.0.0.0/1

Answer (score -1):

Идем на сайт создателя приложения и скачиваем msi инсталер на выбор есть три варианта, ARM, x86 и x64
скачиваем ту версию которую поддерживает ваш процессор.
Мне помог x64 так как у меня обычный современный пк.
ARM архитектура обычно есть только на мобильных процессорах телефоны итп.